# How to reuse EmptyView across fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my app I have multiple fragments that I want to add an EmptyView if there is no data available. Instead of creating one View per fragment, how can I create one and reuse across them?

About the app, each fragment hits different REST APIs to populate a RecyclerView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a single view, inflate it and add it to your parent view. Something like

```
View emptyView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.empty_view, null);
parent.addView(child);
```

Also set the layout parameters as well

If you want it statically added, use

```
<include layout="@layout/empty_view"/>
```